# Robocopy Overwriting Source Files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have a robocopy batch file scheduled to run everyday at 5 PM. It is supposed to mirror a folder on my C: drive to a networked drive. Code is as follows:

```
robocopy "C:\Source_Folder" \\Network_Drive\Destination_Folder /MIR /LOG:backup.log
```

I noticed the problem this morning when I logged in to continue what I was working on yesterday. Everything I had done in my source folder since robocopy had run previously was reverted back to match the destination folder of the last backup. I checked the logs and found that the files I had changed and saved were marked as OLDER even though I had saved them more recently than the previous backup.

I may be simply missing something obvious but I thought the /MIR switch was a one-way operation. How is it that it copied from the destination folder to my source folder? Also why would newer files be marked as OLDER? Luckily I was able to recreate just about everything I did yesterday but I can't have this happen again.

Is there a more suitable switch that I can use to guarantee a one-way copy of my source directory?

Comment: Has the network drive been disconnected and reconnected? The timestamp issue sounds similar to an issue I found once where a mount had a different timestamp because the computer clocks weren't consistent.

Comment: IT says the clocks are consistent with each other and are set to deny access to the drive altogether if they are out of sync.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution but could I add a line to the batch file to wipe out everything in the destination folder before the copy? I'm not transferring a whole lot of data but it's important stuff.

Comment: Are you aware that `/MIR` specifies that `robocopy` should mirror the source directory and the destination directory. This may delete files at the destination because it is equivalent to `/PURGE` + `/E` and `/PURGE` deletes dest files/folders that no longer exist in source.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The problem is that it is leaving my Destination files and overwriting my Source files.